# How can I set custom order use this function

Tags: php, order, categories

I have a sample:

**CODE PHP:**

```
 <ul class="categories-list">
        <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
 </ul>
```

This code displays the category list sorted by name.

What I want to do is to have a custom order ... not by name not by id.

For example, this order:

```
   1. Category with ID 5:

   2. Category with ID 3:

   3. Category with ID 9:
```

How can I do this using the function above?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to [add term meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/) to your categories. In this metafield you will store the string or number that you want to use as a base for your custom order ([tutorial](http://themehybrid.com/weblog/introduction-to-wordpress-term-meta)). Let's say you have generated a meta field called `my_cat_meta` which holds integers that say in which order you want them to be displayed.

Now you can pass this metakey to `wp_list_categories`. This function ultimately relies on [`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/), which explains which arguments the function can take. You can limit the search to terms that have the metakey defined and order according to that metakey. This amounts to:

```
$args = array (
  'title_li' -> '',
  'meta_key' -> 'my_cat_meta',
  'orderby'-> 'meta_key');
wp_list_categories ($args);
```

A slightly hacky way would be to use the 'description' field that is a default field in WP categories. Many themes don't display it, so you could use it to store metadata. In that case you could skip building your own metafield and use:

```
$args = array (
  'title_li' -> '',
  'orderby'-> 'description');
wp_list_categories ($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shuffle() function to get the categories in random order.
Like this,

```
$categories = get_categories();
shuffle( $categories );
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: i think it will only shuffle $categories items every time its gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

[wp_list_categories();](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) give you formatted output,

To display elements for  custom layout you can use get_categories() or get_terms() function.